# I want to fixed the decimal places of the textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery

The function below also calculates the sum on run time. The txtRate is the textbox to be processed for the decimal fix.

```js
$(function() {
  $("[id*=txtRate]").val("0");
});
$("body").on("change", "[id*=txtRate]", function() {
  var rate = parseFloat($.trim($(this).val()));
  if (isNaN(rate)) {
    rate = 0;
  }
  //Update the Rate TextBox.
  $(this).val(rate);
  //Calculate and update Row Total.
  var row = $(this).closest("tr");
  $("[id*=lblTotal]", row).html(parseFloat($(".quantity", row).html()) * parseFloat($(this).val()));

  //Calculate and update Grand Total.
  var grandTotal = 0;
  $("[id*=lblTotal]").each(function() {
    grandTotal = grandTotal + parseFloat($(this).html());
  });
  $("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").html(grandTotal.toString());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

https://tutorial.eyehunts.com/js/javascript-limit-input-to-2-decimal-places-restrict-input-example/#:~:text=Use%20JavaScript%20for%20validation%20input,decimal%20places%20on%20keypress%20input.

Comment: the link does not help me...

Comment: Please add HTML to the snippet I made you. Click [edit], scroll down, click edit above snippet and add relevant HTML to the HTML pane to make a [mcve]

Comment: Perhaps just change `$("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").html(grandTotal.toString());` to `$("[id*=lblGrandTotal]").html(grandTotal.toFixed(2));` ?

Comment: thank you so much sir!! it worked and I have implemented the same on text box